# How to implement Dynamic library Android

Tags: android

I need to develop a shared library which should have one instance for multiple applications..The library will share common functionalists to all the application in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Define you android project as a library (in eclipse right click on the project > properties > android > is library).

Then in the other projects that use this library go again to: right click on the project > properties > android > add library > select the library project.

They should both be in the workspace and open.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Project -> Properties -> Android -> Check "Is Library"**.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.  There are two ways of looking at it:

1. You want to have common code, developed once and then included into multiple projects.  To do this, you need to create *library projects*.  Have a read throw the [Library Projects documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) for more information about how to do this.
2. You want a proper *dynamic library*, such as .dll on Windows, .dylib on mac or .so on *nix.  As Android is effectively an implementation of *nix and java supports native libraries, this is possible.  You need to use Android NDK to write native methods, which will compile into a .so library, which you will then load from your java code.  This is not difficult, but is not trivial either.  Read [Android NDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to understand how this is done.